# How to use crafty chess engine in the gui chess64.exe link provided

Tags: engines, computer-chess

Given below is the crafty chess engine of xboard or winboard version free version.

https://github.com/MichaelB7/Crafty/releases/download/25.2/Crafty-25.2-Win64.zip

Given below is the book

https://github.com/MichaelB7/Crafty/releases/download/25.2/Crafty_Chess_Informant.Opening_Books.zip

Given below is the GUI open version.

https://github.com/SigmaPT/asm.git

I could not able to use xboard or winboard protocol in the gui.

Please help me in fixing the issue. Please tell the command to be inserted in console window of the gui. Please note I request to put crafty chess engine ONLY in GUI and test.Other UCI chess engines are working GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a quick game as White.

```
1.e4 Nc6 2.Ke2 d5 3.Ke3 dxe4

xboard
st 1
e2e4
e1e2
e2e3
```

Logs:

```
./crafty-25.3-gcc
unable to open book file [./book.bin].
book is disabled
unable to open book file [./books.bin].

Crafty v25.3

machine has 8 processors

White(1): st 1
search time set to 1.00.
White(1): e2e4
              time used:   4.80
        time surplus   0.00  time limit 1.00 (1.00)
        depth     time       score   variation (1)
         18->   1.00/1.00     0.33   1. ... Nc6 2. Nf3 e5 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Nc3 Bc5
                                     5. O-O O-O 6. d3 Na5 7. Nxe5 Bd4 8. Nxf7
                                     Rxf7 9. Bxf7+ Kxf7 10. Bg5 d6
        time=1.00(100%)  nodes=5906541(5.9M)  fh1=92%  pred=0  nps=5.9M
        chk=40.8K  qchk=64.5K  fp=1.7M  mcp=1.4M  50move=1
        LMReductions:  1/236.3K  2/183.8K  3/125.8K  4/33.9K  5/1.3K
        null-move (R):  3/295.8K  4/20.0K  5/377
Black(1): Nc6
              time used:   1.00
White(2): Nf3 [pondering]
        time surplus  29.00  time limit 1.00 (1.00)
        depth     time       score   variation (17)
         19     1.15/1.00     0.22   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Be7 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. O-O
                                     O-O 6. d3 d6 7. a3 a6 8. Be3 b5 9. Bd5 Bd7
                                     10. Qe2 Nxd5 11. Nxd5 Kh8
         19->   1.28/1.00     0.22   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Be7 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. O-O
                                     O-O 6. d3 d6 7. a3 a6 8. Be3 b5 9. Bd5 Bd7
                                     10. Qe2 Nxd5 11. Nxd5 Kh8
         20     1.94/1.00     0.26   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Be7 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. O-O
                                     O-O 6. d3 d6 7. a3 a6 8. h3 b5 9. Ba2 Be6
                                     10. Bxe6 fxe6 11. Be3 Qd7 12. Qe2
         20->   2.22/1.00     0.26   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Be7 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. O-O
                                     O-O 6. d3 d6 7. a3 a6 8. h3 b5 9. Ba2 Be6
                                     10. Bxe6 fxe6 11. Be3 Qd7 12. Qe2
         21     4.24/1.00     0.24   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Nc3 Be7 5. O-O
                                     d6 6. d4 exd4 7. Nxd4 Nxd4 8. Qxd4 O-O
                                     9. Qd3 Be6 10. Bxe6 fxe6 11. Be3 Ng4
                                     12. f3 Nxe3 13. Qxe3
         21->   4.56/1.00     0.24   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Nc3 Be7 5. O-O
                                     d6 6. d4 exd4 7. Nxd4 Nxd4 8. Qxd4 O-O
                                     9. Qd3 Be6 10. Bxe6 fxe6 11. Be3 Ng4
                                     12. f3 Nxe3 13. Qxe3
         22    11.23/1.00     0.13   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. O-O Nf6 5. d3 d6
                                     6. Nc3 O-O 7. Bg5 Be6 8. Bxe6 fxe6 9. Qd2
                                     Qe7 10. Kh1 Nd4 11. Nxd4 exd4 12. Bxf6
                                     Rxf6 13. Nb5
         22->  11.51/1.00     0.13   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. O-O Nf6 5. d3 d6
                                     6. Nc3 O-O 7. Bg5 Be6 8. Bxe6 fxe6 9. Qd2
                                     Qe7 10. Kh1 Nd4 11. Nxd4 exd4 12. Bxf6
                                     Rxf6 13. Nb5
         23    15.56/1.00     0.18   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Ng5 d5 5. exd5
                                     Nxd5 6. O-O f6 7. Nf3 Bg4 8. Re1 Nd4 9. c3
                                     Nxf3+ 10. gxf3 Bh5 11. d4 Nb6 12. Be6 Bd6
                                     13. Nd2 Qe7 14. dxe5 Bxe5
         23->  16.08/1.00     0.18   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Ng5 d5 5. exd5
                                     Nxd5 6. O-O f6 7. Nf3 Bg4 8. Re1 Nd4 9. c3
                                     Nxf3+ 10. gxf3 Bh5 11. d4 Nb6 12. Be6 Bd6
                                     13. Nd2 Qe7 14. dxe5 Bxe5
         24    19.01/1.00     0.25   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Ng5 d5 5. exd5
                                     Nxd5 6. O-O f6 7. Nf3 Bg4 8. Re1 Nd4 9. c3
                                     Nxf3+ 10. gxf3 Bh5 11. d4 Nb6 12. Bb3 Be7
                                     13. Na3 Bxa3 14. bxa3 Qd6
         24->  20.78/1.00     0.25   2. (Nf3) e5 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Ng5 d5 5. exd5
                                     Nxd5 6. O-O f6 7. Nf3 Bg4 8. Re1 Nd4 9. c3
                                     Nxf3+ 10. gxf3 Bh5 11. d4 Nb6 12. Bb3 Be7
                                     13. Na3 Bxa3 14. bxa3 Qd6
         25    30.02/1.00     1/22?  2. ... e5      (6.4Mnps)             
ok.

ok.
e1e2
White(2): e1e2
              time used:  35.73
        time surplus  29.00  time limit 1.00 (1.00)
        depth     time       score   variation (1)
         17->   1.01/1.00    -0.94   2. ... d5 3. exd5 Qxd5 4. Ke1 Bf5 5. Nc3
                                     Qc5 6. Nge2 O-O-O 7. Ng3 Qe5+ 8. Be2 Be6
                                     9. d3 Nf6 10. Kf1 Nd4 11. Nge4
        time=1.01(100%)  nodes=6286981(6.3M)  fh1=87%  pred=0  nps=6.2M
        chk=177.9K  qchk=408.3K  fp=2.1M  mcp=805.1K  50move=3
        LMReductions:  1/119.7K  2/76.9K  3/51.9K  4/20.2K  5/1.8K  6/1
        null-move (R):  3/160.8K  4/10.7K  5/175
Black(2): d5
              time used:   1.01
White(3): exd5 [pondering]
        time surplus  57.99  time limit 1.00 (1.00)
        depth     time       score   variation (16)
         19     1.25/1.00    -0.83   3. (exd5) Qxd5 4. Ke1 Bf5 5. Nc3 Qc5
                                     6. Bb5 O-O-O 7. Bxc6 Qxc6 8. Nf3 Nf6 9. d3
                                     e6 10. Kf1 Bg4 11. Ne5 Qxc3 12. Nxg4 Qc4
         19->   1.80/1.00    -0.83   3. (exd5) Qxd5 4. Ke1 Bf5 5. Nc3 Qc5 
                                     6. Bb5 O-O-O 7. Bxc6 Qxc6 8. Nf3 Nf6 9. d3
                                     e6 10. Kf1 Bg4 11. Ne5 Qxc3 12. Nxg4 Qc4
e2e         20     4.67/1.00    -0.71   3. (exd5) Qxd5 4. Ke1 Nf6 5. Nc3 Qc5 6. d3
                                     e5 7. Nf3 Bd6 8. Be2 O-O 9. Kf1 Re8
                                     10. Ng5 Nd4 11. Bh5 g6 12. Bf3 h6 13. Nge4
3        20     4.67/1.00     2/29?  3. ... Bg4+    (7.0Mnps)             
White(3): e2e3
              time used:   4.93
        time surplus  57.99  time limit 1.00 (1.00)
        depth     time       score   variation (1)
         14->   1.01/1.00    -2.57   3. ... dxe4 4. Ke2 Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+
                                     6. Nxf3 Qd6 7. Nc3 O-O-O 8. Ke1 Nf6 9. d3
                                     Nd4 10. Be2 Qb4 11. Kf1
        time=1.01(100%)  nodes=6260401(6.3M)  fh1=86%  pred=0  nps=6.2M
        chk=169.6K  qchk=373.8K  fp=2.4M  mcp=534.1K  50move=2
        LMReductions:  1/100.5K  2/56.5K  3/38.1K  4/16.5K  5/1.0K
        null-move (R):  3/134.8K  4/6.3K  5/23
Black(3): dxe4
              time used:   1.01
White(4): Ke2 [pondering]
        time surplus   1:26  time limit 1.00 (1.00)
        depth     time       score   variation (13)
         16     1.38/1.00    -2.33   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. Nxf3 Bxf3+
                                     7. gxf3 Qd6 8. Bh3 e6 9. Nc3 O-O-O 10. d3
                                     Nf6 11. Kf1 Nd4 12. Be3 Qb4 13. Bxd4 Rxd4
         16->   1.44/1.00    -2.33   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. Nxf3 Bxf3+
                                     7. gxf3 Qd6 8. Bh3 e6 9. Nc3 O-O-O 10. d3
                                     Nf6 11. Kf1 Nd4 12. Be3 Qb4 13. Bxd4 Rxd4
         17     5.31/1.00    -2.52   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. c3 e6 8. d4 Qh4 9. Be3 O-O-O 10. Qe1
                                     Bd3+ 11. Kd2 Qxe1+ 12. Kxe1 Bxf1 13. Kxf1
                                     Nf6 14. Ne2
         17->   5.34/1.00    -2.52   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. c3 e6 8. d4 Qh4 9. Be3 O-O-O 10. Qe1
                                     Bd3+ 11. Kd2 Qxe1+ 12. Kxe1 Bxf1 13. Kxf1
                                     Nf6 14. Ne2
         18     5.34/1.00     1/33?  4. ... Bg4+    (6.3Mnps)             
ok.
         18     7.00/1.00    -2.62   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 e6 8. Qe1 Qe7 9. Kd1 O-O-O 10. Nc3
                                     Nf6 11. Nge2 Ne5 12. Ng1 Nc4 13. b3 Nd6
                                     14. Be3
         18->   7.06/1.00    -2.62   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 e6 8. Qe1 Qe7 9. Kd1 O-O-O 10. Nc3
                                     Nf6 11. Nge2 Ne5 12. Ng1 Nc4 13. b3 Nd6
                                     14. Be3
         19     8.82/1.00    -2.51   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 Nf6 8. Nc3 Qd6 9. Ke1 O-O-O 10. Nge2
                                     Qb4 11. Bg2 Qh4+ 12. Kf1 e5 13. Be3 Bh3
                                     14. Qe1 Qh5 15. Rg1
         19->   8.98/1.00    -2.51   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 Nf6 8. Nc3 Qd6 9. Ke1 O-O-O 10. Nge2
                                     Qb4 11. Bg2 Qh4+ 12. Kf1 e5 13. Be3 Bh3
                                     14. Qe1 Qh5 15. Rg1
         20    10.28/1.00    -2.56   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 Nf6 8. Nc3 Qd6 9. Ke1 O-O-O 10. Bg2
                                     Qd4 11. Ne4 Qa4 12. Ne2 Nb4 13. b3 Qc6
                                     14. N4c3 Bg4 15. Rf1
         20->  10.42/1.00    -2.56   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 Nf6 8. Nc3 Qd6 9. Ke1 O-O-O 10. Bg2
                                     Qd4 11. Ne4 Qa4 12. Ne2 Nb4 13. b3 Qc6
                                     14. N4c3 Bg4 15. Rf1
         21    15.82/1.00    -2.50   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 Nf6 8. Nc3 Nd5 9. Ne4 e6 10. Bg2
                                     Nd4+ 11. Kf1 Bxe4 12. fxe4 Nb4 13. c3 Ndc2
                                     14. cxb4 Nxa1 15. a3 c5 16. Bf4
         21->  16.34/1.00    -2.50   4. (Ke2) Bg4+ 5. f3 exf3+ 6. gxf3 Bf5
                                     7. d3 Nf6 8. Nc3 Nd5 9. Ne4 e6 10. Bg2
                                     Nd4+ 11. Kf1 Bxe4 12. fxe4 Nb4 13. c3 Ndc2
                                     14. cxb4 Nxa1 15. a3 c5 16. Bf4
         22    23.04/1.00     1/33?  4. ... Bg4+    (6.5Mnps)Nc6
```

Comment: I cannot play with graphical user interface which I supplied.

Comment: @Ram I don’t know how the GUI work

Comment: please advise right path to get solution

Comment: @Ram Pay someone an hour rate.

Comment: okay I will do so